# Passing VB.net values to MYSQL procedure and Crystal Report

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

<s>Please help with 2 issues:</s>

1) How can I pass parameter values using vb.net to mysql procedure to be used in the query?

2) Also pass these parameter values to crystal report document as the procedure also fills the crystal report data

Ok so here's what I did, I send the values from vb that I need to crystal report parameter. Now, what I'am trying to do is to send this crystal parameters to my mysql procedure

Here is my **new** vb.net code for printing the crystal report and sending values from my textbox to crystal report parameter

```
    Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument

    cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\Reports\Report1.rpt")

    Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
    Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
    Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
    Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue

    crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = TextBox1.Text
    crParameterFieldDefinitions = _
    cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
    crParameterFieldDefinition = _
    crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("controlid")
    crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues

    crParameterValues.Clear()
    crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
    crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

    With rptReport
        .crReport1.ReportSource = cryRpt
        .crReport1.Refresh()
    End With

    rptReport.Show()
```

Here is my new stored procedure on mysql database

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sreadings`(IN `controlid` INT)
BEGIN

    SELECT
        a.controlid,
        a.data1,
        a.data2,
        a.date1,
        a.date2

    FROM shifts AS a
    WHERE a.controlid = @controlid;
END
```

But loading the report would throw me the error:

```
Failed to retrieve data from the database.
Details: [Database Vendor Code: 1318].
```

Removing **IN `controlid` INT** from the stored procedure as well as the **WHERE a.day_id = @controlid** removes the error but I need to filter my data by the *controlid* provided by the user via the vb interface.

Any input please? Thanks

Comment: have you added the stored procedure to the report? This will create a backing parameter in the report for @controlid by default. Then you can set the value of the parameter using SetParameterValue() through vb code. How else would you do it?
Also on the SP itself why do you use keyword IN, do you have to? I may be wrong on this one as I don tknow syntax.

Comment: @aMazing what do you mean adding stored procedure to the report? I used an ODBC connection to open the stored proc on the report via the database expert, and dragged and drop from there.

My guess is that IN in my stored procedure is what will handle the values coming from the crystal report parameter. I'm relatively new to reporting so I'm not sure about this one.

Comment: OK so you are using odbc. So do have a parameter on the report created when you dropped the fields on the report.?

Comment: Yes. It shows in the report when I preview it.